# What is "~/" directory?

Tags: linux, bash

Maybe not programming related, but I want to reference this directory in c program.

I thought it is $HOME, but when I unset $HOME, I can still cd ~/ in bash.

It is also not $USER's home, since I can be root with USER="another", but the “~/" still point to "/root".

so how bash explains this "~/"?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the little squiggly ~ do in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/267163/what-does-the-little-squiggly-do-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe not programming related, but I
>   want to reference this directory in c
>   program.

If you try to opendir the string literal "~/" in C, you'll find it doesn't exist. It is a Bash/Csh shorthand notation that is expanded by the shell to the home directory. It does not exist as such on the filesystem and so a C program will fail- unless it invokes Bash, for example, and allows Bash to expand the string.

Answer (score 15):

Using home dir information from **/etc/passwd** (6th field).

Comment: No, don't do this. Use (in shell) getent passwd, or in C, getpwent(3). Both will succeed on NIS or LDAP systems where /etc/passwd will fail you.

Answer (score 2):

It is `$HOME`, but changing it's value will not effect expansion. See [this link](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_28.html) for more information.

Comment: Changing its value will, but unsetting it won't.
When $HOME is unset, bash sets it while expanding ~, as can be checked by running

    strace echo ~

On Cygwin I see this line:

   79   56614 [main] echo 2380 cygheap_user::ontherange: Set HOME (from /etc/passwd) to /cygdrive/g

Answer (score 1):

[Bash Hackers Wiki - Documentation - Tilde Expansion](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/expansion/tilde):

> The tilde expansion is used to expand to several specific pathnames:
>
> - home directories
> - current working directory
> - previous working directory

Answer (score -3):

~ is interpreted as home-dir by the shell. it's a "keyword"